# Angular 6 app is not working in safari browser

Tags: safari, angular6, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps, polyfills

Angular app is working fine in IE and chrome but in safari it is not working even not showing any error and tried with polyfill

and here polyfill.ts

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
  import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/client/shim';
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
 import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
 import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

   import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.


import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

and in package.json all are with 6.x version

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? Facing same issue. App works just fine in Google Chrome, but getting blank page in Safari

Comment: Can you pls help any one

Answer (score 6):

Angular 6 support Safari version >= 10. On windows system latest version of safari is 5 and   on Mac it is 12 as of now(1st Aug 2019). If you are verifying on windows safari, it will not work. You need to check it on Mac machine.

You can check safari release history [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history)

Answer (score -1):

You can also try on Firefox browser instead of Safari. It can gives similar results.